# Laravel Hash:check always return false

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing dd () Dump and Die and it returns me different hashs I don't know the reason here is my controller and my Seeder can't detect the error yet I'm learning how to handle the laravel creating my first api. *

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Hash;

class ApiLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $usuario = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if($usuario && Hash::check($request->senha, $usuario->password))
        {
            return response()->json($usuario);
        }
        return response()->json(['messagem' => 'Erro']);

    }
}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {


        $user = new User;
        $user->name = 'Hernandes';
        $user->email = 'hernandes@gmail.com';
        $user->password = bcrypt('12345');
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

**Hello I changed the code but it did not work I looked at the documentation but still not able to, the result still false, I wanted one more tip of what I can do, and thanks for the help**

**ApiLoginController**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Hash;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


    class ApiLoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function login(Request $request){
            $usuario = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            if($usuario && hash::check($request->senha, $usuario->senha)){
                return response()->json($usuario);
            }
            return response()->json(['messagem' => 'Erro']);

        }


    }
```

**UsersTableSeeder**

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use App\User;

    class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {


            $user = new User;
            $user->name = 'Hernandes';
            $user->email = 'hernandes@gmail.com';
            $user->password = Hash::make('password');        
            $user->save();
        }



}
```

Comment: In English, please, or try your question at [pt.so].

Comment: You need to post your question in english

Comment: please format your code correctly.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing) when creating the hash you should use `Hash::make()` instead.

Comment: @PtrTon Not quite: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-bcrypt. `bcrypt()` is available as an alternative to `Hash::make()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's bad practice to bcrypt a password as opposed to hashing it. The reason is because bcrypt can work both ways. you can ENcrypt it AND DEcrypt it if a hacker got the key. A hash only works one way. It ONLY encodes it and there's no way to decode it. So even if a hacker broke into your database and got all your user accounts, he can't access those accounts if the passwords are hashed. This is the security benefit of hashing. It can only check if the user input matches the stored value. A hacker would have to guess millions of strings to gain access and repeat for every user

Comment: Also, hashing and bcrypt are not the same algorithm. So you're checking for a hash value but storing a bcrypt value. so you want to either hash your password on storing or leave it encryped (not recommended) and check its decrypted value in your login controller

Answer (score 1):

In you controller the following condition has some issues:

`if($usuario && hash::check($request->senha, $usuario->senha)){`

1. `hash::check()` should be `Hash::check()`
2. You are using `$usuario->senha`. But in seeder you are saving the field as `password`. Which is the correct one?
3. The blade view or the request is not shown in the question. Make sure you are passing the password in the filed called `senha`. Otherwise, you won't get any value in `$request->senha`.

**Tip:** Before checking hash you can see if they are containing the correct value using `dd($request->senha, $usuario->senha);` at first.

Comment: I tried to put dd ($ request-> password, $ user-> password); but the first one returned me password and the second null,
so I changed dd ($ request-> password, $ user-> password);
then the first came the password and the second the hash.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what is the difference between these two statements, both of your statement seems same `dd($request->password, $user->password)` to me. If one is returning `password` and another one `hashed password` then you can easily check `Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)`. If this answer resolve your issue then don't forget to approve this answer.

Comment: This answer looks correct to me. `Hash::check()` (may or may not be case sensitive, depends on environment) expects 2 parameters, the un-hashed value (given by `$request->senha`) and the hashed value to check against (`$usuario->password`, not `$usuario->senha`, as determined by the `create()` function). Since `$usuario->senha` would simply return `null` (due to Model property access), it's checking the un-hashed string (correct) against `null` (incorrect), which **always** returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You are bcrypting the value on save and checking a Hash value on login controller. They're two different algorithms. See my comment on the original question for more information. Either change your user->save method to be password = Hash::make('userpassword') and check the hash in the login controller or decrypt the password in the login controller and leave your user save method the same.

Comment: But the `bcrypt()` function in Laravel calls `Hash::make()` (via the non-facade method `app('hash')->make()`). Directly from the documentation: "*You may use it as an alternative to the Hash facade:*"

Comment: if you check this fiddle, https://implode.io/00izDC, the hash and bcrypt return totally different things. This is why i'm thinking his login is not working. If i'm understanding this incorrectly, please let me know so I can learn something too.

Comment: Well yeah, every call of `Hash::make()` will return a different hash; that's the point of hashing. Edit your `implode.io` to do two calls to `Hash::make()` and `bcrypt()`: `$password = Hash::make('password'); $password2 = Hash::make('password'); $password3 = bcrypt('password'); $password4 = bcrypt('password');` (4 calls total), then `dd($password, $password2, $password3, $password4);`; You'll have 4 different hashes.

Comment: Also, do a `dd(Hash::check('password', $password), Hash::check('password', $password2), Hash::check('password', $password3), Hash::check('password', $password4));`. All will be `true`.

Comment: Right, i knew that hash returned something different each time. I was under the impression bcrypt was not as dynamic. I also didn't realize bcrypt called the hash method itself. I read in another article that they used different algorithms. Perhaps that was for a different version of laravel? Anyway, I appreciate the info, i learned something in this as well.

Comment: There are 2 algorithms available in newer versions of Laravel, `bcrypt` and `argon2`. You can configure which is used via `config/hashing.php`, and `Hash::make()` will use whatever is configured. But the `bcrypt()` helper function will still call `Hash::make()` even if you're using `argon2`. An argument could be made to have an `argon2()` helper that does that same, but that's likely just extra noise.

Comment: So, after doing some more digging, I realized my error...there's a difference in "bcrypt" and "encrypt"...my answer and subsequent comments were based on this mix up in my head. Apologies everyone!

Comment: Haha that's ok :) Yeah, you never want to encrypt something like a password, as the ability to encrypt suggests that the ability to decrypt is possible. Obfuscation is fine for non-sensitive data, but passwords should never be stored in either plain text or a format that can be un-obfuscated.